# Printing Doubly Linked Lists

Tags: c++, list, linked-list

I'm currently learning how to work with linked lists, specifically, doubly linked lists, and I have come across a problem with my program when I attempt to print it backwards.

Here is the portion of the code that I need help with:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

struct node
{
    int data; //int to store data in the list
    node *next; //pointer to next value in list
    node *prev; //pointer to previous value in list
};

node *appendList(node *current, int newData) //Function to create new nodes in the list
{
    node *newNode; //create a new node
    newNode = new node;
    newNode->data = newData; //Assign data to it
    newNode->next = NULL; //At end of list so it points to NULL
    newNode->prev = current; //Link new node to the previous value
    current->next = newNode; //Link current to the new node
    return newNode; //return the new node
}

node *createList(int maxLoop, node *begin, node *current, node *end) //Function to create list
{
    //Allocate the starting node
    current = new node;
    current -> data = 1; //First data value is 1
    current -> next = NULL; //next value is NULL
    current -> prev = NULL; //previous value is NULL
    begin = current; //This is the beginning of the list

    for (int count = 2; count <= maxLoop; count++) //Loop to fill the list
    {
        current = appendList(current, count*count); //Create new nodes and fill with square numbers
    }
    end = current; //Now we are at the end of the list
    return begin; //Return begin, this is the problem; I can't return end as well
}

void printForward (node *p) //Function to print the list forwards
{
    node *curr = p; //current is the beginning value of the list
    while (curr != NULL) //Continue while current is not at the end of the list
    {
        cout << curr->data << " "; //Print out the data of current
        curr = curr->next; //Move one value along in the list
    }
}

void printBackward (node *p) //Function to print the list backwards
{
    node *curr = p; //current is the end value of the list
    while (curr != NULL) //Continue while current is not at the beginning of the list
    {
        cout << curr->data << " "; //Print out the data of current
        curr = curr->prev; //Move one value back in the list
    }
}

int main()
{
    //Initialize current, begin, and end
    node *current = NULL; 
    node *begin = NULL;
    node *end = NULL;
    int maxLoop = 10; //The number of items in the list

    cout << "The list has now been created." << endl;
    begin = createList(maxLoop, begin, current, end); //function to create the list
    cout << "Printed forwards, this list is: ";
    printForward(begin); //Function to print the list forwards
    cout << endl;
    cout << "Printed backwards, this list is: ";
    printBackward(end); //Function to print the list backwards
    cout << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

The purpose of this program is to create a list, print it forwards, backwards, insert an element, erase an element, and then destroy the list. I have chopped it down to just the create, print forward, and print backward functions.

The issue I have is that in the createList function I am modifying both begin and end but I can only return one or the other. This means that whichever I don't return is still NULL in the main function and therefore does not point to anything. I've tried setting the begin/current/end to not equal NULL but createList won't work if I do that.

Does anyone have any ideas for how I could modify both? Just to be clear, the list **HAS TO** be created in a function, it would be very easy to just initialize it in the main.

Thanks,
Tristan

Comment: You could take the pointers by reference (node *& begin)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is you're copying the pointers, when you should be passing them by reference, i.e., using a pointer-to-pointer or reference-to-pointer rather than just copying the value the pointer in `main` is originally pointing to.  With what you're doing, you're unable to modify the original pointer variable that was declared in `main` ... passing-by-reference will allow you to-do that while also keeping all list setup code within your functions.

So for instance, change

```
node* createList(int maxLoop, node *begin, node *current, node *end)
```

to

```
void createList(int maxLoop, node** begin, node** current, node** end)
```

and then make sure to take the extra dereference into account in the body of your function

Finally, you would call it like:

```
createList(maxLoop, &begin, &current, &end);
```

And do the final assign to `begin` inside the body of the function of `createList` rather than in `main`.

Comment: I understand what you mean by the extra dereference in the function, but how would I go about that? Specifically for the line "current = new node;" Would I say "*current = new node;" or "current = new *node;" or something else entirely?

Comment: It would be `*current = new node;` since `current` would now be a pointer to the original pointer on the stack of the caller to your `createList` function